# How To Open File Dialog And Create File On It?

Tags: java, swing

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCq9H.png)

I opened File Dialog but I don't create the file on it? How?

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
File selectedFile = null;
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (**result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION**) {
    selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
} else {
    confirmExit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your problem is? Are you trying to create a _new file_ with your file dialog? If so, why did you call `showOpenDialog()` instead of `showSaveDialog()`?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new file with file dialog and I'm trying 'showOpenDialog()' and 'showSaveDialog()' but it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a file with `JFileChooser`, you need to use the `showSaveDialog()` method instead of the `showOpenDialog()` like in your snippet. For more information check out [How to use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and check out the [JFileChooser JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Then the next step if the *saving* has been approved, is to actually write the file.
For this, you can use a `FileWriter`.

I put together a small snippet, which opens a `JFileChooser` on a button click, where you can provide the filename, where some `String` will be written to this file.

**Example**:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> buildGui());
    }

    private static void buildGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Save your File");

        // action listener for the button
        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); // create filechooser
            int retVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(frame); // open the save dialog
            if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {    // check for approval
                // create a bufferedwriter with the specified file
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()))) {
                    // write the content to the file
                    writer.write("Your content that shall be written to the file");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(btn);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

[image]